# Outside Scope Access from within Angular forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to do is get the Game ID that is created by the `APIService.postData` for the game.  I need to then take that Game ID and put it into the Angular foreach loops so that on the RESTful side, the foreign key constraints hold true.

How can I get that game ID out of there?
P.S. I am well aware of the scope issue

```
this.createGame = function() {

    APIService.postData('game', '', $scope.newGameData).then(function (data) {
        $scope.newGameID = data.id;
    });

    // Looping through each added class and adding the game_id onto the object in
    // order for the DB insertion to go smoothly on the RESTful side.
    angular.forEach($scope.newGameData.classes, function (key, value) {
        $scope.newGameData.classes[value].game_id = $scope.newGameID;
        APIService.postData('game-class', '', $scope.newGameData.classes[value]);
    });

    // Looping through each added race and pushing the game_id onto the object in
    // order for the DB insertion to go smoothly on the RESTful side.
    angular.forEach($scope.newGameData.races, function (key, value) {
        $scope.newGameData.races[value].game_id = $scope.newGameID;
        APIService.postData('game-race', '', $scope.newGameData.races[value]);
    });

    $scope.newGameData = {
        name: ""
    };
    $scope.race_counter = 0;
    $scope.class_counter = 0;
    $scope.newGameData.classes = [{id: $scope.class_counter}];
    $scope.newGameData.races = [{id: $scope.race_counter}];

    $scope.successMessage = "New 'Game' has been added!";

    $scope.action = 'showGames'; // Default action.
    this.getGames();
    $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

Comment: You populate `$scope.newGameID` from promise after some delay so all your code should be inside promise callback

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't make any sense to me.  Do you need to see anymore of the code, such as the API Service code?

Comment: So, the promise callback (from my understanding) is the data that is in 'data' in the 'then' function.  So, when I do what I am doing with data.id and assigning it to $scope.newGameID does have the proper value.  However, I need to get that value down to the Angular forEach loops and it $scope.newGameID is coming up undefined in those loops because of the scope breakage.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The foreach loops needed to go into the 'then' callback.  The GameID kept coming up undefined because the POST request hadn't actually finished yet.  On top of that, the $scope.newGameData was getting screwed up, so I assigned both arrays to their own local variable and it works great.

```
this.createGame = function() {

    var newGameID = '';
    var classData = $scope.newGameData.classes;
    var raceData = $scope.newGameData.races;

    APIService.postData('game', '', $scope.newGameData).then(function (data) {
        newGameID = data.id;

        // Looping through each added class and adding the game_id onto the object in
        // order for the DB insertion to go smoothly on the RESTful side.
        angular.forEach(classData, function (key, value) {
            classData[value].game_id = newGameID;
            APIService.postData('game-class', '', classData[value]);
        });

        // Looping through each added race and pushing the game_id onto the object in
        // order for the DB insertion to go smoothly on the RESTful side.
        angular.forEach($scope.newGameData.races, function (key, value) {
            raceData[value].game_id = newGameID;
            APIService.postData('game-race', '', raceData[value]);
        });
    });

    $scope.newGameData = {
        name: ""
    };
    $scope.race_counter = 0;
    $scope.class_counter = 0;
    $scope.newGameData.classes = [{id: $scope.class_counter}];
    $scope.newGameData.races = [{id: $scope.race_counter}];

    $scope.successMessage = "New 'Game' has been added!";

    $scope.action = 'showGames'; // Default action.
    this.getGames();
    $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```